# Cannot inflate view

Tags: android, android-fragments

Whenever I try to inflate a view in a fragment my app crashes:

```
...
import android.app.Fragment;

    public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);

            return v;
        }


        ...
    }
```

Exception:

```
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ghang.mimyau.org.bitbucket/ghang.mimyau.org.bitbucket.mainactivity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at ghang.mimyau.org.bitbucket.mainactivity.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:24)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1785)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:887)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1437)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5174)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     ... 11 more
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:617)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4770)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     ... 22 more
```

I know that I could solve this using android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead of android.app.Fragment but I don't want to. Can anyone explain why only support library works in this case and how to make standard library working?

**EDITED**

Comment: Post the entire stack trace.  We can't tell from part of it.

Comment: what's in `myLayout` line #7?

Comment: Can you please post the `MainActivity?`

Comment: ` Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
04-29 21:27:30.402: E/AndroidRuntime(3727):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:617) ` this line is telling me something plase post the XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace is telling you what the problem is here:

> com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment

You are trying to cast an instance of `SupportMapFragment` to an `app.Fragment`. `SupportMapFragment` extends from the support version of `Fragment`; `.v4.app.Fragment`. Either replace `SupportMapFragment` with `MapFragment` or use the support version of `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Layout names cant contain Caps, try changing your xml file name to my_layout.xml instead of myLayout.xml and replace `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout, parent, false);` for `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);`

Comment: Sorry bad example. In actual app all letters are in lower case. Let me edit the quewstion.